# no working LLVM bitcode compiler

Tags: llvm, klee

I need to build KLEE on my Ubuntu 12.04. I followed KLEE website's instructions step by step. I had LLVM 2.9 built. But when I need to install klee-uclibc, and in the process of configuring, it complained that it failed to find a working LLVM bitcode compiler. Does this mean that my LLVM built was unsuccessful? I am new to Linux and new to the testing tool. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please refer to this question:http://www.mail-archive.com/klee-dev%40imperial.ac.uk/msg01825.html

Comment: Have you used options like with-builtin-clang or do you have an existing llvm compatible compiler?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem, but a closer look in [klee document](http://klee.github.io/getting-started/) helped me fix it. Especially look at step (02)(01):

> Install llvm-gcc:
>   Download and install the LLVM 2.9 release of llvm-gcc from here. On an x86-64 Linux platform you are going to need the archive LLVM-GCC 4.2 Front End Binaries for Linux x86-64.
>   Add llvm-gcc to your PATH. It is important to do this first so that llvm-gcc is found in subsequent configure steps. llvm-gcc will be used later to compile programs that KLEE can execute. **Forgetting to add llvm-gcc to your PATH at this point is by far the most common source of build errors reported by new users.**

Hence, make sure that llvm-gcc is installed and a PATH is provided to the executable.